# Calculate conditional cumulative sum

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframes:

```
N=seq(1:18)
Pre=c(0.5, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6)
df1=data.frame(N, Pre)

E=c(3.1, 2.9, 4.4)
Category=c(22,35,36)
df2=data.frame(E, Category)
```

I want to create two new columns in df1 (`cumsum` and `category`)

The values in the `cumsum` column will accumulate until the value is equal to or less than the value of the `df2$E`, when it is greater the `cumsum` will begin again. In the column of `category` the value will be 22,35 or 36, etc.

The result will be

[image]

This is a short example, I need to do this with a very big dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

To get `Category` column we could `cut` `cumsum` value of `Pre` and define the `breaks` as `cumsum` of `E` from `df2` and `labels` as respective `Category` value. Now, we can use this `Category` value as grouping variable and take `cumsum` of `Pre` values in each group using `ave`.

```
df1$Category <- cut(cumsum(df1$Pre), breaks = c(0, cumsum(df2$E)), 
                                    labels = df2$Category)

df1$Cumsum <- ave(df1$Pre, df1$Category, FUN = cumsum)


df1
#    N Pre Category Cumsum
#1   1 0.5       22    0.5
#2   2 0.4       22    0.9
#3   3 0.7       22    1.6
#4   4 0.9       22    2.5
#5   5 0.6       22    3.1
#6   6 0.3       35    0.3
#7   7 0.7       35    1.0
#8   8 0.8       35    1.8
#9   9 0.6       35    2.4
#10 10 0.5       35    2.9
#11 11 0.4       36    0.4
#12 12 0.7       36    1.1
#13 13 0.9       36    2.0
#14 14 0.6       36    2.6
#15 15 0.3       36    2.9
#16 16 0.7       36    3.6
#17 17 0.8       36    4.4
#18 18 0.6     <NA>    0.6
```